# Ask for confirm when closing a tab

Tags: javascript, browser

When I close my page on some browser I want a message box to appear and to ask me if I really want to close the page or not, with two buttons and if I click `No` then this tab won't be closed.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call some JavaScript when the user closes a (popup) window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333833/call-some-javascript-when-the-user-closes-a-popup-window)

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript to check when the browser window is close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805463/javascript-to-check-when-the-browser-window-is-close)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to listen on the [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Hey, you're leaving the site. Bye!";
};
```

This message will show up in kind of a confirmation dialogue. This message will show up right *before* the client unloads the page. That can be a browser close, *but* that can also be a simple navigational action like clicking a link or submitting a form in the page!

You would most probably also like to turn it off (just set to `null`) whenever an internal link is clicked or an internal form is submitted. You namely don't want to annoy endusers with unintuitive behaviour. You can do that by listening on the `click` event of the desired links and the `submit` event of the desired forms. [jQuery](http://jquery.com) may be of great help here since it does that in crossbrowsercompatible way so that you don't need to write >20 lines of JS code for this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return "You're leaving the site.";
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[rel!=ext]').click(function() { window.onbeforeunload = null; });
        $('form').submit(function() { window.onbeforeunload = null; });
    });
</script>
```

You only need to give all external links the defacto standard attribute `rel="ext"` to denote that those are external links.

```
<a href="http://google.com" rel="ext">Google</a>
```

Comment: You don't have to detach the `onbeforeunload` function if you don't want to display the alert box. Just let the function return nothing and the browser will go on as expected (closing the window, going back in history, etc.).

Comment: @Marcel: That's indeed another way of disabling the function. That however require a global and I'd like to avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: If adding the attribute rel="ext" is not doable, you could also compare the href location of the link to your current page.  $('a[href*="'+window.location.host+'"]')

Comment: Updating comment with better solution.  The following selects all links that are not of the following: relative, on the same domain, and not a symbol (#).  

$('a:not([href^="/"],[href*="'+window.location.host+'"], [href^="#"])')

Comment: beforeunload is no longer supported in ios. any other solution?

Comment: beforeunload is no longer supported in ios. any other solution?

Answer (score 8):

use the onbeforeunload event

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Are you sure you want to close the window?";
}
```

This will display a messagebox where the user can choose whether or not to close the window.

**Note that this is not supported by Opera**.

Answer (score 8):

[`onbeforeunload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907(v=VS.85).aspx) fires before [`onunload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536973(v=VS.85).aspx).

You can't cancel the event in `onunload`. `onbeforeunload` allows returning a string from events (e.g. `window.onbeforeunload = function() {return "really leave now?"}`, and the browser will ask the user a question whether they want to leave your page. The page has no say in stopping the event if "Yes" is clicked (that's the way it should be too in my opinion.)

**General points:**

- `alert`, `prompt` and `confirm` aren't allowed in either events.
- Neither is supported in Opera.

**WARNING:** In IE6/7 at least (and possibly IE8 but not FF/Chrome etc) `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` are triggered when anchors/javascript links are clicked on. Some examples:

- `<a href="#myanchor">trigger unload!</a>`
- `<a href="javascript: alert('message!')">trigger unload!</a>`

(MSDN is as good a source as any, considering it's non-standard and that Firefox/Chrome/Safari seems to largely have copied the implementation from IE.)