# Execute function before refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, yui, page-refresh

On my HTML page, when the user clicks / presses <kbd>F5</kbd> button the page refreshes, but before it refreshes I want to execute a function or a simple alert.

User can click on refresh button, press <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Using core JavaScript, jQuery or YUI.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript function, on web page close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858057/javascript-function-on-web-page-close)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function(event)
    {
        return confirm("Confirm refresh");
    };
```

Comment: Well, for me this does not solve the problem described. It triggers the confirm box (with a predefined and probably browser specific text) on all events leaving the page. I.e., also on form-submission. There it is really irritating and not intended! Any thoughts?

Comment: Then you need to explain som more about whats specific about your problem... Show us some code (jsfiddle ?) and tell us what browser your using...

Comment: Chrome blocks it

Comment: This in an outdated Solution. Confirm block will not work inside the onbeforeunload. https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5349061406228480

Answer (score 8):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    return '>>>>>Before You Go<<<<<<<< \n Your custom message go here';
});
```

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-stop-a-page-from-exit-or-unload-with-jquery/

Demo: http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/jQuery/jQuery-stop-page-from-exit.html

Answer (score 4):

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function(){
        return confirm("Do you really want to refresh?"); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

the jQuery related event is:

```
$( window ).on('unload', function( event ) {
    console.log('Handler for `unload` called.');
});
```

Works great for me.

Comment: The question is for 'before' unload, this event will not work for that, read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event