# What is "Confirm Form Resubmission" and how is it triggered?

Tags: browser

### Context

The internet does not like "Confirm form resubmission".

While trying to answer a SO question about [trying to make the prompt occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652950/how-to-get-confirm-form-resubmission-when-user-trying-to-refresh-browser/27653133?noredirect=1#comment43725219_27653133), all I could find were resources regarding how to prevent it from happening.

### Question(s)

1. What are the ways that users trigger the prompt in modern browsers? What's really happening when someone tries to refresh a form?
2. How could a developer programmatically trigger the prompt?

Extra kudos if you can find source documentation...

Answer (score 0):

This is a php-related issue, 
Whenever the method of the form submission is "post" this dialogue will appear.
No nead to do anything else

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have any documentation for this? Please give more details...