# Alert is not working when user try to refresh browser page using f5,ctrl+5 using jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have requirement of show alert to the user when user try to referesh tab in browser it should get alert "if you alert this page you will loose data" but I am using jquery for this still it is not working .

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){ 
  alert("Don't refresh you will loose your all data?");   
  //or
  confirm("are you sure want to refresh this page !");
});
</script>
```

Comment: try `window.onbeforeunload=function(e){return "";}`, notice returning something in this case is mandatory. See if this is helpful.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar itried that also still no response

Comment: you can try @Himansu Upadhyay answer

Comment: Don't use `alert` it will just alert ,can't prevent from refresh .... Just acknowledging

Comment: Yes, always use confirm as it provides two buttons, Ok and Cancel which returns true and false. Refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript before leaving the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080269/javascript-before-leaving-the-page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute function before refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308336/execute-function-before-refresh)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display a custom message in the beforeunload popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This with return

> Note:
> NOT all browsers support this

```js
  $(window).on("beforeunload", function (event) {
    return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

> Additional Info :
>
> Google Chrome removed support for custom message in ver 51
>
> Opera removed support for custom message in ver 38
>
> Mozilla Firefox removed support for custom message in ver 44.0
>
> Apple Safari removed support for custom message in ver 9.1

Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38880926/6299088

Comment: `.bind()`? What year is this?  Superceded in *2011*, now deprecated: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: update: ah you've just *copied* an existing answer word for word.  tut tut.  You should vote close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

It will be like this:

```
 $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){ 

    return confirm("are you sure want to refresh this page !");
  });
```

Comment: @MSp told you before :) , returning is the key.

Comment: @shailesh kumar kachhi will you please tell me why we need return here initially  I didn't used return so it was not working

Comment: @AbhishekKumar yes it is write actually I didn't used that initially thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
        window.location.reload();
        return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
});
$(window).on('keydown', function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.keyCode == 116 || (event.key === "r" && event.ctrlKey)){
        alert("Don't refresh you will loose your all data?");
        confirm("are you sure want to refresh this page !");
    }
});
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){ 
  alert("Don't refresh you will loose your all data?");   
  //or
  confirm("are you sure want to refresh this page !");
});
</script>
```

Comment: when press f5 it is wroking but when right click of mouse and in that if you select refresh then not getting alert , same with ctrl+r.

Comment: Let me check for that.

Comment: I updated my answer which also works for `Ctrl + r`. Please give it a try.

Comment: @MSp, I have updated my answer. Now please check it all. It should work for all your requirements. Please comment how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Bind `beforeunload` event :

```
 $(window).bind("beforeunload",function(){ 
            return confirm("Do you want to refresh this page?");
    });
```