# How to show alert from prompt box true value when user click ok when prompt box will get using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing one project so in that I need if user try to refresh page using f5,ctrl+r then prompt will ask if you refresh page all your data will loss if click yes one more alert should get and if click cancel on this case also alert should get but I am not getting any alert if click on ok or cancel button in prompt box.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script>
     $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){ 

  return  aa=confirm("are you sure want to refresh this page !");

  if(aa===true){
       alert('You will loose your data');
   }
   else{
       alert("Ok continue your work");
   }
  });
<script>
```

Comment: `return  aa=confirm` should be `var aa=confirm`

Comment: @freedomn-m after chnaged to  like this I am  not getting prompt box with message 'are you sure want to leave this page'

Comment: That's a whole different issue... here's a question from yesterday that covers your new issue (which is actually a duplicate of one from 2010) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51531287/alert-is-not-working-when-user-try-to-refresh-browser-page-using-f5-ctrl5-using/51531457#comment90034427_51531457

Comment: Oh wait - just spotted who created that question :)

Comment: As the answer you've already been given shows, this was removed from browsers about **8 years ago** as it was being abused by spammers/advertisers/hackers/etc

Comment: @freedomn-m so how to solve this issue still I am not getting prompt box

Comment: Probably better to read the full answer that the one you accepted was copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38880926/2181514