# Is it possible to get custom message while closing Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have multiple workstations where I sync R project code on github. I want to get an alert  to commit and push my code in github before closing R studio.

I found ways to get customized alert messages in case of browsers mostly useful in case of jscript, java query coding but I do not find any option for Rstudio .

I do not have remote server access so once I forget to commit my code having access to code on a different workstation is difficult. Hence, I want to customize an alert while closing R Studio and leaving the current workstation.

here are few examples
[Execute function before refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308336/execute-function-before-refresh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to build a function called `.Last` This is documented on the help page `?q`. `.Last` will be run when you quit. Note that R will exit after `.Last` has completed *unless* `.Last` throws an error, so if you want a chance to go back and save your work,  you will probably want to call `stop()` in your function if you have not saved your work.   A simple example might be:

```
.Last <- function() {
    cat("Did you remember to save to Git?\n")
     flush.console()
    while(TRUE) {
        response <- readline(prompt="Did you save to Git? ")
        if(grepl("Y", response, ignore.case=TRUE)) { 
            cat("OK. Bye\n")
            return() 
        } else {
            if(grepl("N", response, ignore.case=TRUE)) { 
                cat("Better save\n")
                stop() 
            } else {
                cat("Please answer Yes or No\n")
                flush.console() }
        }
    }
}
```