# do some work in page when page reloaded in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i want to do some worked in angular when page is reloaded and to some worked when page was loaded .

for example i want to add some items in local storage when item was going to refreshpage ( load page ) and remove some items when page complete loading .

in other word i want do some work after and befor refreshing page in angular .

**how can i solve this problem ???**

Comment: Hey! Could you let us know what you have tried so far, and why it didn't work?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308336/execute-function-before-refresh) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make JavaScript execute after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular Life cycle hooks to achieve that..

Check the docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).