# Is there a function, like componentWillUnmount, that will fire before the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want a function, to send a request to a server (don't care about response) before a user refreshes the page.

I've tried using the `componentWillUnmount` approach but the page refresh doesn't call this function. e.g.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const ComponentExample => () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            // componentWillUnmount in functional component.
            // Anything in here is fired on component unmount.
            // Call my server to do some work
        }
    }, []) }
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: componentDidMount() is the function you should be using.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308336/execute-function-before-refresh) answer for native event

Comment: `componentDidMount()` will fire when the component loads. I want a function to fire when the page is about to refresh.

Comment: Thanks @kunquan but that native event gives a confirmation dialog. I want a function, so I can do some work before the page refreshes

Comment: You can do some work inside that function. The dialog is just the default behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try listening for the [window.beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event.

> The **`beforeunload`** event is fired when the window, the document and its
> resources are about to be unloaded. The document is still visible and
> the event is still cancelable at this point.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unloadCallback = (event) => { ... };

  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
}, []);
```

Note: This will respond to *anything* that causes the page to unload though.

Note 2:

> However note that not all browsers support this method, and some
> instead require the event handler to implement one of two legacy
> methods:
>
> - assigning a string to the event's returnValue property
> - returning a string from the event handler.

Comment: Perfect. That's what I was looking for. For anyone looking here, I had to add a line to the call back:
`unloadCallBack = e => {
   // do work
delete e['returnValue']
}`

Comment: It's advisable you use `beforeunload` instead of `unload`

Comment: @Joshua Thanks. In my testing I didn't notice a difference between the two, but upon reading the official docs I agree.

Comment: @DrewReese For the `unloadCallback` function, if it returned a `e.returnValue = "Are you sure?"`, this would produce an alert with two options: "Cancel" and "Leave". If the user selects "Leave", do you know how to call some function, say `someFunction()`, right before the page refreshes? [This is a bit of an indirectly related question to the OP!]

Comment: @penguin Not that I'm aware of currently. I think the idea is to either do the work in the `unloadCallback`, or ask the user what they want to do, and if they choose leave then the browser manages the resources. In other words, `unloadCallback` ***is*** that "some function". Browser maintainers have made it clear they don't want pages to keep users around any longer than they need to when users have indicated they want to leave. No more Columbo style ["but hey, just one more thing..."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYgUPD2khtw) nag screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, almost, by checking if the page has been refreshed.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API

Example:

```
if (window.performance) {
  console.info("window.performance is supported");
  console.info(performance.navigation.type);

  if (performance.navigation.type == performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {
    console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
  } else {
    console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
  }
}
```