# I want to call an api when a react app is closed in browser (by closing the tab)

Tags: reactjs

I am using the react-router package. I want to send an API request when the tab is being closed.How can i do that in react.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64966559/is-there-a-function-like-componentwillunmount-that-will-fire-before-the-page-i/64967211#64967211

Comment: I have used `unload` event listener and `navigator.sendBeacon()` method to solve this