# Show A Warning If Page is Closed or Refreshed in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

My problem is that I need the user to confirm if he wants to continue to close or refresh the page. If he press `No`, it won't close nor refresh the page.

Please take a look at my code so far:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", alertUser);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", alertUser);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: is your `alertUser` defined like this? `const alertUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = "";
  };`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64967211/8690857 See the second note regarding browser support.

Comment: @DrewReese. Can you complete it? Like there's a yes/no to select. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to display a sort of confirmation before leaving the page then follow the [beforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) guidelines

> According to the specification, to show the confirmation dialog an
> event handler should call preventDefault() on the event.
>
> However note that not all browsers support this method, and some
> instead require the event handler to implement one of two legacy
> methods:
>
> - assigning a string to the event's returnValue property
> - returning a string from the event handler.
>
> To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created
> in `beforeunload` event handlers unless the page has been interacted
> with, or may even not display them at all.
>
> The HTML specification states that calls to `window.alert()`,
> `window.confirm()`, and `window.prompt()` methods may be ignored during
> this event. See the [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#user-prompts) for more details.

I just tested this in chrome and safari and it works. I don't have a windows box, but this should cover most cases.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unloadCallback = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = "";
    return "";
  };

  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
}, []);
```

[image]
[image]

[image: Edit put-a-warning-if-page-refresh-in-reactjs]

Comment: Thank you. How do you customize message by the way?

Comment: @Joseph You can't AFAIK... likely part of the whole "...to combat unwanted pop-ups..." business. I think it is generally highly discouraged to implement nag screens like this, the focus being that you may want to clean up resources and such before the page unloads, not bother the user, or more specifically, prevent them from doing what they want in the browser.

Comment: Hi there, I have a question. Instead of showing the browser modal can I render my custom modal component?

Comment: @CripsyBurger With this method, no, you get what you get from the browser. Any more these days it is more and more recommended to adjust your app's logic to handle page reloads or navigations away without user interaction, i.e. bothering the user. If data is partially updated, i.e. dirty, either try the above to let the user know, just run some logic when the page unloads to save data or whatever, or ignore it and let the dirty pages get garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Alert Image]

I think this answer is pretty straightforward, using `useEffect()` hook and `window.onbeforeunload`, we can do this very easily

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.onbeforeunload = () => true;
  ...
  return () => {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
  };
}, []);
```

This will ask the user everytime before hitting reload and leaving the site.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for this.

https://dev.to/eons/detect-page-refresh-tab-close-and-route-change-with-react-router-v5-3pd

Browser Refresh, Closing Tab, and back and forward buttons, are all explained.

Try this:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
    const unloadCallback = (event) => {      
        const e = event || window.event;
        //console.log(e)
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e) {
          e.returnValue = ''
        }
        return '';
          
    };
    
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
    return () => {
      //cleanup function
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
    }
    
  },[])
```

Comment: *"try this"*: that is essentially the code that was posted [more than a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68933242/5459839).