# How to detect Crtl + Shift + R and Browser Reload button on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

How to detect user has click the **Reload** button on the browser:

[image]

I am trying to use the `useBeforeunload` library and javascript listener method `beforeunload` to detect however the `event.preventDefault()` and set the return value to `false` still doesn't do anything instead it keeps reloading the page even though I put some `Modal` tag to notify user that your going to reload the page and it did popup the modal right after I hit the **Reload** button but it force to reload the page. I also have issue in terms of detecting the **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **R** it seems it didn't detect for some reason even though I tried to capture it using `keydown` listener.  What I wanted to achieve is to prevent it from reloading the page and show the modal to notify the user.  Please see my code below:

*App.jsx*

```js
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const onClose = () => setShow(false); // this will show the modal


  const disableF5 = ((e) => {
    if(window.location.pathname.includes('/apple/')) { 
      if(!config.enableRefresh) {
        if (e.which === 116 || e.keyCode === 116 || (e.key === "r" && e.ctrlKey) || (e.key === "r" && e.shiftKey && e.ctrlKey)) { // ctrl + shift + r never detected
          e.preventDefault();
          setShow(true);
          return;
        }
       }
    }
  });

  const handleReloadCancel = useBeforeunload(event => {
    event.preventDefault(); // this should prevent it from reloading the page
    setShow(true)
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', disableF5);
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleReloadCancel);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', disableF5);
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleReloadCancel);
    }
  }, [])
```

I also tried using this method `window.performance.navigation.type == 1` but it didn't help as well.  Any ideas on how to achieve my goal? Thanks!

Comment: Why would to attempt to prevent someone from using their browser as they see fit? Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68932621/put-a-warning-if-page-refresh-in-reactjs/68933242#68933242

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, we need to prevent it because this is a different page for transaction purpose (very sensitive information) and if they do so, the data being set is lost and they have to forced you to log you out from the application and try it again.  So it should be that way.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, I think that popup (window.alert) message should be removed and also the it should not show the popup message and instead the modal should show and prevent it from reloading the page.  Is this possible?

Comment: Not really. Major browsers seem to be pretty hard against anything that blocks navigation actions.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the detection of Ctrl + Shift + R:

Had the similar objective today and noticed that whenever the **Shift** key is among the pressed ones, then you have to check for the capital "**R**" letter.

Changing condition from `(e.key === "r" && e.shiftKey && e.ctrlKey)` to `(e.key === "R" && e.shiftKey && e.ctrlKey)` may do the trick for you as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).