# How to change the route upon browser refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a scenario when user clicks on browser refresh, the page routing has to be changed.
I have tried using the below code during mounting/unmounting phase, but no luck.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  window.addEventListiner("beforeUnload", changeRoute);
  return()=>{
    window.removeEventListiner("beforeUnload", changeRoute);
  }
},[])
const changeRoute = (e) =>{
  e.prevantDefault();
  pros.history.push('/somepage');
}
```

With this code, I can see the url is changing to '/somepage' and re-navigating to the same page again. It is not moving to '/somepage'. Can anyone advice me please?

Comment: At the point where the URL is changed, the refresh is already in progress. One approach I would try would be: Store a "closed date time" in local storage/cookies (during your `beforeUnload`), then whenever the app is opened, check if that date is within the last e.g. 5 seconds, and automatically redirect at that point.

Comment: If the user is reloading the page, or closing the tab/window, why are you trying to change the default behavior? Why not instead just redirect to `"/somepage"` when the app mounts?

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo in your question, but `pros.history.push` seems like it should be `props.history.push`. Anyway, does something like my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68933242/8690857) help?

Comment: I think DBS has a sound suggestion and approach. Most browsers are making it more difficult to override any "unloading" behavior as a way to prevent nag screens and other undesirable behaviors as it ultimately effects the users of their browser.