# How to use <Prompt /> in "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-router-dom

I am using the **Functional component** for React Project. I like to add functionality like `<prompt />` that is if the user accidentally presses the refresh, or back button or changes the URL, and many more than one alert box appears. But I can not use the `<prompt />` tag in my project because it is not available in **"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"**.

Comment: Does something like this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68933242/8690857

Answer (score 0):

This alternative approach to do that, useeffect and browser back button method to do apply your prompt code.

Comment: For the form in react, I used Formik. To know whether the form is durty or submitter ((formik.dirty && formik.isValid) || formik.isSubmitting) Can u show me the demo code? It would be very helpful for me.