# Refresh functionality in angular

Tags: angular

Looking for refresh functionality.

I'm trying to show custom popup for the case when page is refreshed but unable to override the browser default.

Comment: have you tried this one [link][1]?


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9308361/6581776

Comment: You can't prevent a tab to close, and refresh is considered like a close-and-reopen. So it can't be done

Comment: Browsers put specific, and different, limitations on what you can do before unload for safety and anti-spam reasons. Period.

Comment: Thanks for the response but above solutions are not working..pls let me know if any..