# Javascript browser close event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have used localStorage to store the value of a variable.The problem is that localStorage never resets from what I managed to find on the internet.I am interested to reset localStorage when the browser is closed.

Is there a way to do that?

I have tryed using  $(window).unload from jQuery but that detects changes related to the window and it resets the localStorage variable to soon.

Comment: Why would you be using `localStorage` to store a value that you DON'T want to persist?

Comment: I only the value to exist until the browser is closed

Comment: Why not just store the data in a session cookie which is automatically destroyed when the browser is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser/10311375#10311375) in which I explained how to detect browser close, $(window).unload doesn't work always.

```
<script>
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

 if (localStorage) {
    localStorage.clear();
 }
 };
</script>
```

But, yes I would recommend to use **Cookies** or **session variable** which would be destroyed on browser close instead of localStorage.

Comment: why not `if (localStorage) localStorage.clear()` in all cases?

Comment: @mplungjan the question says **I am interested to reset localStorage when the browser is closed.**

Comment: @mplungjan why not just `localStorage.clear()` directly? :P both will cause error if `localStorage` is not supported. The troll here is that `if( anything )` will cause `ReferenceError` if `anything` is not defined

Comment: I meant: `window.onbeforeunload = function() { if (window.localStorage) localStorage.clear()}` to be completely clear. Gopi's "for safari" part will also fail if there is no localStorage defined

Comment: There's indeed no need for the `if (e)` block. That is only necessary if you need to set a return value, as with the confirm to close question. Instead, you should check whether `localStorage` is supported by the browser, as explained by @mplungjan.

Comment: @mplungjan yup maybe, but I was in doubt that if alert does not work for window.onbeforeunload, so this **may** not work, thats why I added this piece of code.

Comment: @mplungjan ok, got it. my bad. The `if(e)` block is only necessary if you need to set a return value, got that now. & I edited the answer to make it appropriate.

Comment: This will clear `localStorage` any time the page reloads or relocates, which is what happens with javascript memory already, I don't see the point.

Comment: @Esailija didn't get you. localStorage doesn't clear on page reload.

Comment: wait what the ?? @gopi1410 Esailija is suggest sessionStorage.. not localStorage

Comment: @Esailija yeah I get you, the asker wanted to accomplish it with localStorage, so I answered this. It is the same as sessionStorage.. :P

Comment: @gopi1410 no, he can accomplish this with `{}`. and `sessionStorage` is not the same thing, it only clears out when you actually close the browser or tab itself. this clears out `localStorage` anytime the tab refreshes or changes location. I.E. no different to using a javascript object with `{}`

Comment: Well actually, not different to javascript objects is false, it will write to disk (and synchronously, too) instead into memory.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) instead.

> sessionStorage
>
> This is a global object (sessionStorage) that maintains a storage area
>   that's available for the duration of the page session. A page session
>   lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page
>   reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause
>   a new session to be initiated.