# How to trigger a javascript alert when user close browser tab / browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i trigger a  javascript alert when user close browser tab / browser in all web browser ( chrome / Firefox )

Comment: catch `onbeforeunload` event.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onbeforeunload` event on `window` object.

you can go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10311375/7820078) answer for browser compatability.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
       return 'Close Tab?';
    };
```

Comment: the above script doesn't work on my firefox as many stackoverflow answers pointed out this one is there any clear example you can share

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

Handle `onunload` & `onbeforeunload` events and call `alert` in the event handling function

Comment: can you share an example as i am learning javascript