# Alert when leaving page with unsaved form(typescript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have ts script with code  to handle `"unsaved"` text inputs

Here is code of script

```
export class Unsave {
    public static unsave_check(): void {
        let unsaved = false;
        $(":input").change(function(){ 
            unsaved = true;
            console.log(unsaved);
        });

    function unloadPage(){ 
        if(unsaved){
            return "You have unsaved changes on this page. Do you want to leave this page and discard your changes or stay on this page?";
        }
    }

    }
}
```

And then I use it in other script like this

```
`window.onbeforeunload = Unsave.unsave_check();`
```

But as I see, `function unloadPage()` is never hit, why so?
I see that unsaved is changing value to true. But when I go back, I get no alert message.

How I can fix this issue?

thank's for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confirmation before closing of tab/browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser)

Comment: what does `$(":input")` represent ?. Is it a text field or a checkbox or a button?

Comment: It's text field @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: And this part of code is working well @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: you are not calling the unloadPage(); you only defined it.

Comment: Okay, how I can call it?@AkhilAravind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should call `Unsave.unsave_check()` when the form has been initialized and bind the `unloadPage` on the `window.onbeforeunload` (and you can make it also static - or the other method to non-static and instantiate the object).
You should also move the value `unsaved` from the function scope, maybe to a private class field so both methods can access it

```
export class Unsave {
    private unsaved: boolean = false;

    public register() {
        $(":input").change(() => {
            this.unsaved = true;
            console.log(this.unsaved);
        });
    }

    public unloadPage() {
        if (this.unsaved) {
            return "You have unsaved changes on this page. Do you want to leave this page and discard your changes or stay on this page?";
        }
    }
}

// call this after form init
const unsaveChecker = new Unsave();
unsaveChecker.register()
window.onbeforeunload = () => unsaveChecker.unloadPage()
```

Comment: I think it's not work. Same as answer above. for some reasons it changing value in `register()` method , but not calling unloadPage.

Comment: Thank's dude so much!

Comment: Can I refactor it, to just call `Unsave.***` , and this is all?

Comment: yes, just make the methods static and you can call Unsave.***.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `unloadPage` in `window.onbeforeunload` with something like this :

```
export class Unsave {
    private static unsaved: boolean = false;
    public static unsave_check(): void {
        Unsave.unsaved = false;
        $(":input").change(function(){ 
            Unsave.unsaved = true;
            console.log(Unsave.unsaved);
        });
    }
    public static unloadPage(): string { 
        if(Unsave.unsaved){
            return "You have unsaved changes on this page. Do you want to     leave this page and discard your changes or stay on this page?";
        }
    }

}
```

Then 
`window.onbeforeunload = Unsave.unloadPage();`
and somewhere else in your code you have to call `unsave_check`...
For instance:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    Unsave.unsave_check();
});
```

Note: `unloadPage` and `unsave_check` are not consistent naming... one camel case, one snake case ?

Comment: Yeah, but I think you miss `}` bracket after unsav_check() and also now I get this error

`Type '"You have unsaved changes on this page. Do you want to leave this page and discard your changes o...' is not assignable to type 'void'.`

Comment: So maybe second function must be `:string`

Comment: @JohnDoe true, changed

Comment: Seems not works. When I go to previous page I don't get alert

Comment: I calling unloadPage like this `window.onbeforeunload = Unsave.unloadPage();`

unsave_check() working well and changing value