# How to display popup with custom HTML on browser close tab using JavaScript/Jquery ? I have custom HTML popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display custom HTML Popup when user close web browser using Jquery/Javascript.I have googled it but not found any solution to achieve that.

Please help me. I am stuck since many days !!

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to code anything?

Comment: When you say popup do you mean launch another window/tab, or a modal popup in the current page? The former is not possible

Comment: you'd have to do it on the mouse leaving the page, not when a tab / the broswer is closed

Comment: Please confirm yourself. You want to popup on "Browser" OR "Tabbed" close event?

Comment: I tried that only display message: 

window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'Sure?';
};

Comment: I want custom HTML in new dialog

Comment: Please confirm yourself. You want to popup on "Browser" OR "Tabbed" close event? 
Comment : I want to open custom popup

Comment: This method  window.onbeforeunload Only displays message

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to prevent users from just closing the tab, you can provide them an alert if you use the following:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'Sure?';
};
```

Original answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10311375/6524598

Comment: I want to display HTML popup

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using the only available methods "onbeforeunload" or "unload" it is not possible to customize the popup displayed when the browser or browser tab is closed, because for the two methods you need to return a string.

*Infact you cannot use your own dialog boxes (or jQueryUI modal dialogs) to override beforeunload method.*

Comment: Any other option ?

Comment: You will have to show the html popup in another context, not connected to the closing event of the browser. You could connect the popup to mouse / keyboard events if the user performs a particular action that makes him leave the current page, for example if you click on a link to go to another page / website... It depends on your final purpose.
or use an ajax call to mark the browser close event, and act accordingly by creating logs.