# Prevent user from clicking the "X" button to close the Shiny app on certain conditions

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Is there a way to bar the user from clicking the "X" button on a browser to exit the app forcefully if certain boolean variable in the app is not TRUE?

I feel this has to do with connecting Shiny with Javascript somehow. Saw an example that display a popup prompt when the user closes the browswer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048802/r-shiny-ask-confirmation-before-closing-app-tab). But in this example, the user can still forcefully leave the browser.

But I don't know anything about Javascript to go on from there.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You cannot disallow a user from closing the browser window. That would be a huge security concern. It's not something that the browser lets you do.