# Confirm box for saving data after closed chrome tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to display confirm box(yes or no) for saving data after closed tab in google chrome extension.

Also when user click on yes/no button then call function so that i can save data in cache/cookies/localstorage.

Comment: Have you bumped with [this SO post (Confirmation before closing of tab/browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser)?

Comment: No. That's web page code which you shared but the question of google extension development.