# How to put alert ,if rows are dragged and dropped and update button is not clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-sortable, onbeforeunload

I have a table whose rows are made draggable using sortable property as mentioned below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tblLookup1 tbody").sortable({
            items: 'tr',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            axis: 'y',
            dropOnEmpty: false,
            start: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.addClass("selected");
                
            },

            stop: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.removeClass("selected");

            },
            receive: function (e, ui) {
                $(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
            }
        });
    });

    
</script>
```

Now, once rows are dragged and dropped I have created an update button which is used to update the new order to database.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn CreateButtonColor" id="btnSave" value="Update"/>
```

Now I wish to have an alert, if the user drags and drops the rows and forgots to click on update, how to put warning so that user cannot navigate to other pages without saving?

warning something like below

```
if (confirm('Do you want to save the data before leaving?')) {
  // Update code
}
else
{
// do nothing
}
```

where shall I place the above block of code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10311375/3807365

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require, set a flag on the table when something is dropped. When the user attempts to leave the page you can then check to see if that flag is set and display the warning:

```js
$(function() {
  // set the flag on drop
  let $tbody = $("#tblLookup1 tbody").sortable({
    // ... settings
    receive: function(e, ui) {
      $tbody.data('is-dirty', true).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
    }
  });

  // remove the flag when submitting the form through the update button
  $('#yourForm').on('submit', () => $tbody.data('is-dirty', false));

  // check the flag when the user leaves the page and display 
  // a message if it's set
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    if ($tbody.data('is-dirty')) {
      return 'Do you want to save the data before leaving?';
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: ``` $('#yourForm').on('submit', () => $tbody.data('is-dirty', false));``` ,for this line I need to clarify one thing , since I am not using any form but just a table with update button, what shall I replace #yourForm with...?

Comment: any idea about this?

Comment: In that case use the `click` event of your `button`

Comment: I had tried that , but the problem is that the alert is not even appearing if I click on refresh or navigate to a different page, not sure why the beforeunload is not triggering...
not sure if 'is-dirty' is getting assigned any value as I put alert statements inside the if block and nothing returned

Comment: Why is the page being transferred when you click the button? If it's not in a `form` then it won't do anything - unless you have some other JS code attached to it. In which case you need to remove it