# Enhancing Call Persistence in Twilio Voice JavaScript SDK: Managing Sessions Beyond Browser Closure

Tags: twilio, session-state, browser-close

I am seeking a solution to address the issue of Twilio calls ending when the browser is closed. I want to implement a mechanism to prevent call termination upon browser closure.

I am currently developing a Twilio calling feature based on the reference provided: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-node. The calling functionality works well, but I encounter an issue when closing the browser or terminating the Progressive Web Application (PWA); my calls are being disconnected.

I have implemented notifications for call status changes using webhooks, and they work until the call is disconnected. Now, I am looking for a solution to manage the calling session in Node.js. Is it possible to handle this type of situation, and if so, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't as the browser is required to keep the websocket open. This is a browser issue and not a Twilio issue. Your option is to find a way to get the browser to ask the person not to close the tab or window. This post offers some suggestions on "[Confirmation Before Closing Of Tab Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser)".

What we do instead is use an SIP hardphone (like a Polycom) or a SIP softphone. The browser is used to control the phone but the connection is maintained within the SIP hardphone/software.

There is likely a way to use a Conference to keep a call active even if the agent's browser client session ends and then re-join that Conference but the caller would just sit there waiting for the agent to return which is a not great customer service experience.