# Block F5 key using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, keyboard-shortcuts

I have written some code to block the <kbd>F5</kbd> key on web page. It's working fine except when I have to display a large amount of data. If you press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key during the loading duration in which the HTML and JavaScript code is generated, my page gets refreshed.

Here is the code that I am using to block the <kbd>F5</kbd> key:

```
document.onkeydown = fn;

var fn = function (e){ 
    if (!e) 
        var e = window.event;
    var keycode = e.keyCode;    
    if (e.which) 
        keycode = e.which;
    var src = e.srcElement;  
    if (e.target) 
        src = e.target;
    // 116 = F5     
    if (116 == keycode) {
        // Firefox and other non IE browsers
        if (e.preventDefault) { 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            e.stopPropagation();
          // Internet Explorer
        }else if (e.keyCode){ 
            e.keyCode = 0; 
            e.returnValue = false; 
            e.cancelBubble = true; 
        } 
            return false; 
    }
});
```

I think this code is not working when the HTML and JavaScript code is generating.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a semicolon on the last line?

Comment: Rather than blocking F5, just warn the user when they leave the page while said process is happening. More often than not they're clicking the refresh button rather than pressing F5 anyway.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858057/javascript-function-on-web-page-close/2858115#2858115

Comment: @KevinB If you're forcing full screen like I do on my project which disables F5, you don't need to worry about someone clicking a refresh button because they can't see one.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.onkeydown=disableF5;
var version = navigator.appVersion;

function disableF5(e) 
{   var keycode = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

    if ((version.indexOf('MSIE') != -1)) 
    {  if (keycode == 116) 
       {  event.keyCode = 0;
          event.returnValue = false;
          return false;
       }
    }
    else 
    {  if (keycode == 116) 
          return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have some very simple code for preventing F5 that I use myself. Works in IE, Chrome and Firefox:

```
function disableButtonsDown(e) { 
    if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) e.preventDefault(); 
};
$(document).on("keydown", disableButtonsDown);
```