# AngularJS - using $window.onbeforeunload to call an API before the browser closes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onbeforeunload

I have an application where a resource is created when the user enters that page. If they do not properly save that resource an API call is called to the backend to delete it. Closing the browser before saving is one scenario.

Here I use [WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) to listen for a close event and fire a function before the window closes.

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
     if (notSavedFlag == true) {
         //call an api function
         $http.delete(...)
                    ...
     }
}
```

However, the API call does not fire when closing the browser window (and I put a breakpoint in the backend to check if it fires)

**What is wrong with my code?**

Comment: FYI: There is no way to guarantee that the http call will make it to the server.

Comment: You need sync request ($http send async always) and even then it may not fire.

Comment: @epascarello Looking at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627111/how-to-call-a-function-before-leaving-page-with-javascript you can call a function before it closes

Comment: Yes, but the browser will kill off open http requests as it exits.