# How to customize confirm() popup text like Gmail does?

Tags: javascript, browser, gmail

In Gmail when you are in middle of composing a email and attempt to navigate away from the page they pop up a confirm() dialog box
The first line of the box is "Reload site?"

However when I use `confirm('message')` in the popup that is generated the first line of text always contains the text `localhost says`

From what I have seen the `confirm()` only has one parameter `message`

How is Gmail able to customize that text to say Reload site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function before leaving page with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627111/how-to-call-a-function-before-leaving-page-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail uses `window.onbeforeunload` which bypasses the security restriction of showing the sites domain and instead replaces it with a context specific header.

`window.onbeforeunload = () => 'some message'`