# How to set window.alert when redirecting

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I'm crawlling some web pages for my research.
I want to inject javascript code below when redirecting to other page:

```
window.alert = function() {};
```

I tried to inject the javascript code below using WebDriverWait, so that selenium may execute the code as soon as the driver redirect to new page. But It doesn't work.

```py
while (some conditions) :
  try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
                lambda driver: original_url != browser.current_url)
    browser.execute_script("window.alert = function() {};")
  except:
    //do sth


  original_url = browser.current_url
```

It seems that the driver execute javascript code after the page loaded because the alert that made in the redirected page is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem in other way.
I tried and tried again with `browser.switch_to_alert` but it didn't work. Then I found that it was deprecated, so not works correctly. I checked the alert and dismiss it in every 1 second with following code :

```
while *some_condition* :
        try:
            Alert(browser).dismiss()
        except:
            print("no alert")
            continue
```

This works very fine, in Windows 10, python 3.7.4

Answer (score 1):

**Chrome 14+** blocks alerts inside `onunload` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080331/3368011)

But, I think the following questions may help you:

- [JavaScript before leaving the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080269/javascript-before-leaving-the-page)
- [How to call a function before leaving page with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627111/how-to-call-a-function-before-leaving-page-with-javascript/28627390)
- [JavaScript before leaving the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080269/javascript-before-leaving-the-page/21061009)

Comment: I tried it just now. I replaced "window.alert = function() {};" to "window.onbeforeunload = function(){ window.alert = function() {};}". But unfortunately as I referred, it seems that the javascript code injects after the page's javascript loaded. The page's alert showing again.

Comment: I think you don't need the whole code. I mean you don't need to make web driver wait. Just use:
```browser.execute_script("window.alert = function() {};")```

Comment: The reason why I posted this question is that the executed javascript code is useless after redirecting to other page. It works well if I stay in one page, but if the page redirects using location.href or else, it doesn't last. So that's why I made the web driver wait until redirecting, and execute ```browser.execute_script("window.alert = function() {};")```

Comment: I understand what you mean, I have found several ways but not sure tho.

Comment: Have you tried onHashChange event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange

Comment: Thanks for your concern, Chootti. I also tried that but didn't work properly. :( I think the script executes after redirection. I solved my problem in other way, please see my self-answer.