# How to prevent the form submission multiple times to payment gateway to avoid multiple transaction(its a payout application)

Tags: javascript, php, css

Some of the users are refreshing the page while they have been credited with the amount..
Askdetails.php
In this page we are requesting the customers to provide bank details/upi id details , once they enter and press on submit , the submit button gets disabled and transfers to payment gateway page.....
Meanwhile from askdetails to cashgram the users may refresh the page and now the cashgram dashboard is getting requests multiple times from the same customer.
How to avoid this...

One solution i found is to display message "don't refresh the page"
Another to avoid multiple submissions..

What ever i am trying my application stops working with the change in these 2 pages

Any help..
Its very important to me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a function before leaving page with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627111/how-to-call-a-function-before-leaving-page-with-javascript)

Comment: Disabled the button after someone click submit

Comment: single-use hidden token in your form would help, if the server checks this before accepting the (re)submission