# Can't work beforeunload function in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build action before the user close the web tab in Reactjs. This time, I try to use `beforeunload` but it's not working. How can I try to run it when the web tab is closed.

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.onClose());
}

onClose = () => {
 ...
}
```

`onClose` is not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975068/calling-js-functions-on-browser-tab-close
Maybe it might help to you.

Comment: does the `componentWillUnmount` not work for you.

Comment: I set up `componentWillUnmount` but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

`this.onClose()` in `window.addEventListener` is actually `window.onClose()`.

Try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const self = this;
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", self.onClose());
}
```

#### Update

It would be a good practice to remove event listener on `componentWillUnmount`.