# Event on leaving the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I write a function that will display an alert when the user tries to leave the page?

I've been thinking about a 1px high div at the very top of the website, and when the user hovers it an alert appears, but I can't place it there, the less html code I place for this purpose the better.

Another method I've been thinking of is unload, or beforeunload events, but they seem to be deprecated.

How can I do this?

Comment: `but they seem to be deprecated` How do you figure?

Comment: Here are some more informations from an early post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858057/javascript-function-on-web-page-close

Comment: `onbeforeunload` has this in mind, but keep in mind that 99% of scenarios that might leverage this are really invasive and its a dick move (hence why browsers don't really handle it consistently). The 1% scenario where it might be OK is when there is an unsubmitted form the user will regret closing. For that case, look into existing libraries that reference "form tainting".

Comment: Correction : look into "dirty forms" to find solutions for minimizing risk of forms being closed unsaved ("are you sure…" alerts). Tainting was a similar idea for checking if content was potentially compromised by external sources.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I write a function that will display an alert when the user tries to leave the page?

The only way to do that is to use `onbeforeunload`, and you get **very** little control: Basically, you can supply a message which will probably (but only probably*) be shown to the user. The user will get two choices: Go ahead and leave, or stay.

`onbeforeunload` is a very unusual event. Here's how you hook it:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (youWantToShowAMessage) {
        return "The message goes here.";
    }
};
```

> Another method I've been thinking of is unload, or beforeunload events, but they seem to be deprecated.

I'm not aware of either of those being deprecated. What you can *do* in them is very restricted (for good reason), but until there's a replacement, `onbeforeunload` serves a useful purpose: It lets the web page tell the user they may be losing something (e.g., unsaved work) when they leave. The current mechanism which only allows a message and very, very few other actions is a decent one: It puts the user in control, but lets the page be useful.

---

* Mozilla has flirted with just showing a generic message, not showing your message.